# How to get md5 output but tab separated?

Tags: bash, shell

I can use `md5 -r foo.txt > md5.txt` to create a text file with the md5 of the file followed by a space and then the local path to that file .. but how would I go about getting those two items separated by a `TAB` character?

For reference and context, the full command I'm using is

```
find . -type f -exec \
  bash -c '
    md=$(md5 -r "$0")
    siz=$(wc -c <"$0")
    echo -e "${md}\t${siz}"
  ' {} \; \
  > listing.txt
```

Note that the *filepath* item of md5 output might also contain spaces, like `./path to file/filename`, and these should not be converted to tabs.

Comment: What is the `md5` command? The usual command to compute and MD5 checksum is `md5sum` (and it doesn't have a `-r` option). Are you using the `openssl md5` command? I know that if you have a symlink named `md5` pointing to `/usr/bin/openssl` it will compute and MD5 checksum, but at least on my system that symlink isn't installed by default.

Comment: It seems `md5` is on BSD  and the `md5sum`  for linux, I just tested in on FreeBSD., most probably the OP is on Mac os.

Comment: @Jetchisel: Is it the openssl version of `md5`? If so, `md5` is probably a symlink to `openssl`, and `md5 -help` will show about 26 lines of information, most of which is irrelevant to MD5 checksums.  (It matters because the GNU coreutils `md5sum` command and the OpenSSL `md5` command format their output differently, which is very relevant to this question.)

Comment: @Erics Since not everyone will have the same `md5` command you're using, it would be helpful to show the exact output of `md5 -r somefile` in your question.

Comment: @KeithThompson, on my FreeBSD it is an executable ELF b4bit, so no symlink here. also on BSD's the `-help` or `--help` or `-h` is an error.

Comment: @KeithThompson @Jetchisel Yes, Mac OS. The `-r` option is "Reverses the format of the output.  This helps with visual diffs." The actual format is described in the first sentence of the question: `<md5sum><space><filepath>`.

Comment: @Erics: I still suggest showing a command and its output to your question, formatted as code. It would be easier for future readers to understand it at a glance.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is another option:

```
find directory/ -type f -exec md5 -r '{}' '+' | sed 's/ /\t/' > listing.txt
```

This will replace the first space on each line with a tab.

(Note that the file you're redirecting output to should not be in the directory tree being searched by `find`)

Comment: My `md5sum` (version 8.30 form GNU coreutils) prints two spaces between the hash and the file name. Therefore I would use `sed -E 's/ +/\t/'`.

Comment: @Socowi It sounds like OP isn't using that program.

Comment: @Jetchisel No, spaces in the filename are not a problem here as `sed s/a/b/` replaces only the *first* occurrence of `a` (note that there is no `g` flag at the end).

Comment: @Jetchisel Why would I tell it to replace all spaces and not just the first?

Comment: Reading comprehension failed on this side... anyways the OP also wanted to do the `wc` part.

Comment: @Jetchisel OP can use their `find` command. Appending `| sed ...` after it will transform the first space (the one after the hash) into a tab.

Answer (score 2):

Try the builtin `printf` and [P.E.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) parameter expansion, to split the `md` variable.

```bash
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
  md=$(md5 -r "$0") siz=$(wc -c <"$0")
  printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "${md%% *}" "${md#*"${md%% *}"}" "${siz}"
' {} \; > listing.txt
```

Output

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e        ./bar.txt              0
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e        ./foo.txt              0
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e        ./more.txt             0
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e        ./baz.txt              0
314a1673b94e05ed5d9757b6ee33e3b1        ./qux.txt              0
```

- See the online manual for bash [ParameExpansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
- The local man pages if available. `PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*parameter\ expansion' man bash`

Comment: What does "P.E." mean? (I think I know what you mean, but a lot of readers won't.)

Comment: Personally, I'd drop the "P.E.". I don't think I've ever seen that abbreviation. Just calling it parameter expansion is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are simply left with spaces between the hash and file name that you don't want.  A quick pass through awk can clean that up for you.  By default input awk delimiter is any amount of white space.  Simply running though awk and printing the fields with a new OFS (output field separator) is all you need.  In fact, it makes the pass through `echo` pointless.

```
time find . -type f -exec bash -c 'md=$(md5 -r "$0"); siz=$(wc -c <"$0"); awk -vOFS="\t" "{print \$1,\$2,\$3}" <<< "${md} ${siz}" ' > listing.txt {} \;
```

Personally, I would have ran the output of that find command into a while loop.  This is basically the same as above, but a little easier to follow.

```
time find . -type f | \
while read -r file; do
    md=$(md5 -r "$file")
    siz=$(wc -c < "$file")
    awk -vOFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$3}' <<< "${md} ${siz}"
done > listing.txt
```

Comment: Does awk do the right thing if the filepath item contains spaces, like `./path to item/filename` ?